# Laravel validation : different messages with the same rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I have a validate like this :

```
if ($a > $b) {
  $rule['to'] = 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after:from';
else {
  $rule['to'] = 'required|date_format:Y-m-d H:i:s|after:now';
}
```

Can i have the two different messages like:

> 'to.after:from' => 'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
>   'to.after:now' => 'bbbbbbbbbbb',

Sorry my message is japanese so i don't up here.
I want to know if it has the way to show two messages with the same rule.
I tried to change the defaul message of laravel

```
'after'=> 'The :attribute must be a date after :date.',
```

but didn't work.
Please help me.
Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your query in my example demo. I think Laravel cannot prived for the multiple attribute validation.

So here you can just Do as you done.

`'to.after' => 'Your message',`

You can create a Request to handle the validation separately from the controller

Comment: I have already created a request file, but the rules is almost the same so i can't separate that file :(  
And thank you for your answer ~^^~